# SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, miniconda, openai-api

Upgraded on my Windows 10 Pro Miniconda (conda version : 23.3 and 3.10.10.final.0). After the upgrade I cannot make any API calls. For example call to OpenAI that was previously working (prior to the upgrade) fails with the following errors. Tried every possible trick and suggestions incl uninstall & reinstall certfi, urllib3==1.25, but none seem to help. Any pointers?

```
2023-04-08 13:29:46.169 Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /v1/chat/completions

2023-04-08 13:29:46.280 Retrying langchain.llms.openai.completion_with_retry.<locals>._completion_with_retry in 4.0 seconds as it raised APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.openai.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/chat/completions (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))).
```